# Visualisation of decentralized network

Tags: node.js, websocket, blockchain, distributed, p2p

I've made a decentralized node network using WebSockets with use of Nodejs. I would like to visualize this network with a graph. To visualize the whole network I need all nodes connected to each other, but there is a problem - in the decentralized network there is no central point. How I can get all connected nodes from any node? Let's say we have a connection:

```
A <-> B <-> C
```

[picture of the network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV1y7.png)

Like you can see now you can visualize the network from B, but what about visualizing the network from A, C?

How **A** know about **C** while drawing graphs? Should I also attach peers of connected nodes ( all peers of B) and then all nodes of next nodes - C? What would be the best way to get all peers connected to each other? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph search algorithms could be of use :D Common ones are [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). The general gist of the approach is to start with any node and visit its neighbours while keeping track of which ones you have already visited (so you don't have to go over them again).

In your case I think it would be sensible to start with any random node, and do the process iteratively. I found a fantastic explanation [here](https://www.goodtecher.com/leetcode-323-number-of-connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/), please check it out.

This is a fun exercise actually

Comment: Oh okay, So It's like I thought. I need to get every node peers list and then go iteratively inside them to check everyone. I will need to add this as a http request so I can get list of all nodes from any node. Will check it for sure. Thanks for tip.

Comment: but what is the best approach to get nodes of a node? Should I send connection with all peers list already or make a HTTP request while running a search to every node? I will need to get each node http server to ask for their nodes.

Comment: yes I agree, I think something like pinging other nodes should be very simple :D

Comment: Good, all I need to make a bst or dst through nodes, and when I get whole list of nodes and it's connections then I can use this data to visualize the data

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need a visualisation of the network if its decentralised?

Comment: It's for my university project. Professor said that it will be more interesting if you could actually see the whole network as a graph :D

Comment: Awesome! Sounds really cool, good luck!